# If $G \setminus H$ be a finite set, then $G$ is finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a proper subgroup of it. I should prove that if $G \setminus H$ be a finite set, then $G$ is finite group. Any suggestion?

Comment: $G \setminus H$ is a union of cosets of $H$

Comment: @DerekHolt I think $G\setminus H$ denotes set difference in this context, otherwise the claim is wrong.

Comment: @Chr, yes, it's set difference, but yes, the set difference is a union of cosets of $H$.

Comment: Right, I somehow didn't realize that.

Answer (score 3):

for any  $a \in G-H$, $aH \cap H$ = $\emptyset$ ...so $H$ is finite so $G$ is finite